# MVC 2 Area Authentication Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication

Using MVC 2, if I setup my root web.config with forms authentication (there is no locations section), and I go to a page outside an area (off of the root), I get redirected to the login page as one would expect.  However, if I go to a page in an area, I don't get redirected as expected.  Do I need an additional web.config somewhere in the area or do I possibly have something mis-configured?

Also, I have been sure to clear all cookies and start from a new session and browser just in case something was holding over from a previous login.

I really did not want to have to maintain locations or multiple web.config files since the whole site needs authentication.

If it helps, I am using Visual Studio 2010 and started with a MVC 2 template.

Warning: I have only had 2 cups of coffee this morning so it could be a short circuit between the chair and the keyboard...

Thanks,

--Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web.config authorization should not be used with an MVC application.  Instead, apply the [Authorize] attribute to the controllers you wish to protect.  If all of your controllers site-wide need authorization, consider having a BaseController with an [Authorize] attribute and having all of your controllers site-wide subclass the BaseController.

Comment: In retrospect, I knew that, but for the life of me it took reading the answer to remember it.  Thanks a bunch for giving me a virtual smack on the back of the head...